# GroupJoin, SelectMany, GroupBy and Sum

Tags: c#, entity-framework, linq, entity-framework-6

I am trying to do a 'left outer join' in linq using GroupJoin and SelectMany, but then I also want to aggregate the result using GroupBy and Sum.

But when I execute the code below, I get:

> System.NotSupportedException: 'The entity or complex type '...tableB' cannot be constructed in a LINQ to Entities query.'

```
Repo<tableA>().All()
    .Where(i =>
        (i.Date >= dateF && i.Date <= dateT)
        &&
        i.EndOfMonth
    )
    .GroupJoin(
        Repo<tableB>().All().Where(i => (i.fieldX = ...somevalue... )), 
        dt => dt.DayIndex, scd => scd.DayIndex, (dt, scd) =>
            new {
                dt = dt,
                scd = scd,
            }
    )
    .SelectMany(
        jn => jn.scd.DefaultIfEmpty( new tableB { Count1 = 0, Count2 = 0 }), // runtime error here
        (dt,scd) => new { dt=dt.dt, scd = scd}
        )
    .GroupBy(i => i.dt)
    .Select(i => new CountListItem
    {
        Date = i.Key.Date,
        CountField1 = i.Sum(o => o.scd.Count1),
        CountField2 = i.Sum(p => p.scd.Count2)
     })
     .OrderBy(i => i.Date)
     .ToList()
```

When I just do `DefaultIfEmpty()` I get the error:

> System.InvalidOperationException: 'The cast to value type 'System.Int32' failed because the materialized value is null. Either the result type's generic parameter or the query must use a nullable type.'

I am assuming, I must admit, this is because Sum encounters null values.

I tried `i.Sum(o => o.scd.Count1 ?? 0`, but then it says:

> Operator '??' cannot be applied to operands of type 'int' and 'int' [sic]

I also tried `DefaultIfEmpty(new { Count1  = 0, Count2 =0})` but this gives me>

> ... type cannot be inferred.

How can I get this to work?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Avoiding the first exception is easy - simply use the standard pattern for *left outer join* with parameterless `DefaultIfEmpty()`.

The second problem originates from the difference between SQL and LINQ (C#) query data types. SQL queries support `NULL` values natively and can return `NULL` even if the source expression is not nullable. As you noticed with the last attempt, LINQ (and in particular C# compiler) is not happy with that syntax.

The trick is to promote the non nullable type to nullable using the C# cast operator and *then* apply the null-coalescing operator to the resulting expression:

```
CountField1 = i.Sum(o => (int?)o.scd.Count1 ?? 0),
CountField2 = i.Sum(o => (int?)o.scd.Count2 ?? 0),
```